# Finding handle in email templates in Magento

Tags: magento, email-templates

I'm trying to edit this email template:

```
/app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/order_new.html
```

I'm trying to edit the order totals part, but in the file above it has this code

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
```

that gets the data I need to edit. Does anyone know where I can find this `sales_email_order_items` handle so I can make the edits? I'm using Magento CE 1.4.1.1

Thanks~

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are three places where the `sales_email_order_items` handle are mentioned:

1) bundle.xml

2) downloadable.xml

3) sales.xml (probably the one you need)

Additionally here are the templates it calls:

```
email/order/items.phtml
```

`sales/order/totals.phtml` (probably the one you want)

```
tax/order/tax.phtml
```